# mediawiki: How to override css commands of a given skin?

Tags: css, mediawiki, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-extensions

I have edited the `common.css` file to change the size of the headers. More precisely, my code is

```
#bodyContent h2{font-size:100px; color: blue;}
#bodyContent h3{font-size:100px; color: blue;}
#bodyContent h4{font-size:100px; color: blue;}
#bodyContent h5{font-size:100px; color: blue;}
```

It does not work. It seems that another `css` file is loaded *after*  `common.css`. I think it is the `css` file related to a skin.

**How can I override the `css` commands of the skin in `common.css`?**

Comment: You try with !important? Like color: blue !important;

Comment: Have you tried `!important` although not highly recommended.

Comment: OK guys you made my friend's day ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `!important`.

```
#bodyContent h2{font-size:100px !important; color: blue !important;}
#bodyContent h3{font-size:100px !important; color: blue !important;}
#bodyContent h4{font-size:100px !important; color: blue !important;}
#bodyContent h5{font-size:100px !important; color: blue !important;}
```